# Data Migration From Oracle To SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, oracle11g

I have an Oracle database in which there is one or more table. I also have blob data, i.e. images are stored, now I would like to move that data to Sql Server database. What is the best way to do this?

I would like to test it for one table migration which contains image data in the Oracle database and move it into SQL Server table.

How do I test for migrating data from one table from Oracle to SQL Server?

But first thing I would like to confirm is that whether Image data moving from Oracle DB to SQL Server DB is possible, is there anything that has to be taken care of while migrating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend having a look at [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (SSIS).

SSIS is a ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) tool built for Data Warehousing, but it's also great for migrating data. It basically replaces the old SQL Server Data Transformation Services (DTS), and is a robust and fast-performing tool allowing you to move data from one system to another (which includes Oracle), while giving you the ability to transform data where necessary.

It also has work-flow capabilities, allowing you to set up an execution path (i.e. load client data prior to loading invoice data).

While building up the individual steps, you can easily have a look at the data coming in and flowing through the different objects you set up.

Best of all is that if you run at least SQL Server Standard Edition, SSIS basically comes with it for free.

Lastly, regarding the question about images, blobs are just blobs. Streams of binary data. I haven't tried migrating images from one to the other, but I see no reason why it would not work.

Comment: Thank You for the reply, let me go through the link you provided, I would come back if I have any doubts

Comment: My major doubt is, whether BLOB data would be migrated safely after data migration from Oracle to SQL Server ?

Comment: Why should it not? You can always try running a test on a table with a few rows, and see if what ends up in SQL meets your needs. 

Here's a link to someone on MSDN asking on the best approach to take, with the answer also being to use SSIS: 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservermigration/thread/eea59b00-fb32-4f4b-be85-5d3c9ab2189c/

Comment: You're most welcome. I hope it helps you out. SSIS is a very powerful and fun to use tool :)

Comment: In sql server, which is the best suitable datatype to store the image and for data migration from oracle to sql server point of view, Image or VarBinary(Max) ? and why ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at **Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant** commonly known as "SSMA".
If you want to migrate from oracle to SQL Server then it will help you alot as it can automatically convert all the oracle objects into SQL Server and it is very easy to use.
It even tells you that what you can convert and what you can't convert. For the things that can not be converted automatically you can easily convert them manually by searching on the internet a little bit.