# Migrating Oracle table with Blobs to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I have a large Oracle table (4+ million rows) with a column of type BLOB that I need to import into a SQL Server 2014 database. What is the best approach to this? I have successfully exported some data using SQL*Loader to .ldr files including the blob values. Is it possible to import these files into SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133378/data-migration-from-oracle-to-sql-server

Comment: Unrelated, but: 4 million rows is not consider "large" these days

Comment: "large" is always related to the space you have to fit it in :)